# Selenium Web-driver Click Button

Tags: python, selenium

[Python 2.7, Selenium Web-driver]

So there's this Website:

```
<div class="flex-module-header">

<h3><span class="trend-location js-trend-location">Greece Trends</span></h3>
  <span class="middot">·</span> <a role="button" href="#" data-modal="change-trends" class="change-trends js-trend-toggle">Change</a>
```

And I want to click the button:

```
<a role="button" href="#" data-modal="change-trends" class="change-trends js-trend-toggle">Change</a>
```

And I've tried everything (trying to locate by xpath, class etc.), and I can't seem to be able to do what I'm looking for.

I basically want to click the button, that's all.

Comment: Show us the whole HTML page, this element may be placed within an iFrame

Comment: You still haven't put what you tried. Please add the code that you have tried and what the result was.. errors, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you didn't provide error stack trace and tried code, Assuming you didn't use `WebDriverWait` yet to wait until element visible and clickable. So I'm giving the example with this as below :-

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Change")))
link.click()
```

**Note** :- Before using this, make sure element is not present inside a `frame` or `iframe`. If element is present inside a `frame` or `iframe` you need to switch that frame before finding the button as `driver.switch_to_frame("frame name or id")`.

Hope it helps...:)